# meteor paging (infinite scroll) with just limit option

Tags: mongodb, meteor

May i know is it possible to do infinite loading data just by using increment limit option ? Scenario below explain the question

1. on a page, query find(..) with limit 10
2. on same page, query find(..) with limit 20
3. on same page,  query find(..) with limit 30
4. .. continue..

Is each call to find return only set of 10 result Or  1 return 10, 2 return 20 , 3 return 30 from server? Is this scalable or will eventually cause out of memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the telescope project that uses this approach at: telesc.pe

Also look at the subsmanager package by meteorhacks. This will save subscriptions if you switch pages in iron router.

Only documents that haven't already been downloaded by the client will be downloaded.